# Why django inlineformset not updating?

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I am using inline formset to insert data from 2 model with relation, the create view was success, but i have problem when it need to update data or add new data in update view,
I figure out that the inlineformset doesn't valid in form_valid.

This is my code

Update View

```
class ProductUpdateView(DashProductMixin, DashUpdateView):
    """ProductUpdateView."""
    model = Product
    form_class = product_forms.DashProductForm
    template_name = 'dash/product/update.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Override get context."""
        if self.request.POST:
            # context['harga_bertingkat_formset'] = HargaBertingkatFormset(self.request.POST)
            context['harga_bertingkat_formset'] = HargaBertingkatInlineFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            # context['harga_bertingkat_formset'] = HargaBertingkatFormset(queryset=HargaBertingkat.objects.none())
            context['harga_bertingkat_formset'] = HargaBertingkatInlineFormset(instance=self.object)


        return context


    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Override form valid."""
        context = self.get_context_data()
        harga_bertingkat_formset = context['harga_bertingkat_formset']
        # product = form.save()

        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if harga_bertingkat_formset.is_valid():
                print("#HRg", harga_bertingkat_formset)
                harga_bertingkat_formset.instance = self.object
                harga_bertingkat_formset.save()
        return super(ProductUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My form

```
class DashProductHargaBertingkatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Product Harga Bertingkat Form."""
    class Meta:
        model = HargaBertingkat
        exclude = ()

HargaBertingkatInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Product,
    HargaBertingkat,
    form=DashProductHargaBertingkatForm,
    fields=['max_quantity', 'min_quantity', 'price'],
    extra=1,
    can_delete=True
)
```

This my template

```
{{ harga_bertingkat_formset.management_form }}
                                <table id="item_table" class="table table-hover custom-table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="col-form-label">Min quantity:</th>
                                            <th class="col-form-label">Max quantity:</th>
                                            <th class="col-form-label">Price:</th>
                                            <th>Tambah</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    {% for frm in harga_bertingkat_formset %}
                                        <tr class="current-form-row">
                                            <td>
                                                {% render_field frm.min_quantity|add_error_class:"is-invalid" class="form-control" %}
                                                {% for error in frm.min_quantity.errors %}<div class="invalid-feedback">{{ error }}</div>{% endfor %}
                                                {% if frm.min_quantity.help_text %}<span class="form-text text-muted">{{ frm.min_quantity.help_text }}</span>{% endif %}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                {% render_field frm.max_quantity|add_error_class:"is-invalid" class="form-control" %}
                                                {% for error in frm.max_quantity.errors %}<div class="invalid-feedback">{{ error }}</div>{% endfor %}
                                                {% if frm.max_quantity.help_text %}<span class="form-text text-muted">{{ frm.max_quantity.help_text }}</span>{% endif %}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                {% render_field frm.price|add_error_class:"is-invalid" class="form-control" %}
                                                {% for error in frm.price.errors %}<div class="invalid-feedback">{{ error }}</div>{% endfor %}
                                                {% if frm.price.help_text %}<span class="form-text text-muted">{{ frm.price.help_text }}</span>{% endif %}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <span class='btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-lg btn-add-row' title='Tambah harga bertingkat baru'>
                                                    <i class='flaticon2-plus-1'></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

How can i solve this problem?
any solution?